# A woman's secret

Tags: riddle, word

If a woman loses this, as happens quite often,

then her child must protect the secret of what was lost.

What is this secret?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Would this be

> her maiden name? Women often lose their maiden name when they marry (which happens often); and "what is your mother's maiden name" is a very common security question online, so you might want to keep it secret!

Comment: That's right! Well done :)